# How to assess the significance of r2 values across models

Tags: statistical-significance, structural-equation-modeling, amos

I want to know whether (and how) I can test whether the difference in r2 values across two SEM models is significantly different.

I have conducted a study where participants completed one of two questionnaires. All content for the questionnaires was the same across groups except that in one questionnaire the target behaviour was referred to with a cognitive descriptor word and in the other the descriptor was affective.

I can't make any firm claims about whether one of these models affords better prediction unless I can test that there is a significant difference in the prediction across models. Would there be a way to do this, given the questionnaires were slightly different.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an information criterion instead.  $R^2$ is built on the assumption the model is true and you are running two competing "true" models.  Obviously, *at least* one is not.

If the only difference between the two models is a single question, then you should strip away everything except the two variables and test their predictive powers directly.  The format of the questions will determine how you test for a difference.

The "no difference" hypothesis would be the simplest.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. It isn't a single question that differs between the models, all questions in one questionnaire include the cognitive descriptor and all questions in the other version of the questionnaire include the affective descriptor. I will look into using an information criterion.